# Turtle Program slowing down after a while. Tried clearing screen and deleting but no effect

Tags: python-2.7, memory-management, turtle-graphics

```
# set up the environment
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgpic("space_invaders_background_new.gif")
turtle.fd(0)
turtle.speed(0)
turtle.bgcolor("black")
turtle.ht()
turtle.setundobuffer(None)
turtle.tracer(20,0)

# draw white boundaries around
class Game():   
    def draw_border(self):
        #Draw border
        self.pen = turtle.Turtle()
        self.pen.speed(0)
        self.pen.color("white")
        self.pen.pensize(0)
        self.pen.penup()
        self.pen.goto(-400, 400)
        self.pen.pendown()
        for side in range(4):
            self.pen.fd(800)
            self.pen.rt(90)
        self.pen.penup()
        self.pen.ht()

game = Game()
game.draw_border()

# player 1 and his actions

class Bullet(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.hideturtle()
        self.shape("arrow")
        self.penup()
        self.speed(0)
        self.color("white")
        self.fd(0)
        self.goto(0, 0)

# player class
class Player(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self, spriteshape, color, startx, starty):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self, shape = spriteshape)
        self.hideturtle()
        self.speed(0)
        self.penup()
        self.color(color)
        self.fd(0)
        self.goto(startx, starty)
        self.left(90)
        self.showturtle()

    def move(self):
        self.fd(10)
    def turn_left(self):
        self.lt(20)
    def turn_right(self):
        self.rt(20)
    def accelerate(self):
        self.move()

# Define Enemy1 class

class Enemy1(turtle.Turtle):

    a=[] # to store the bullets per enemy

    def __init__(self, spriteshape, color, startx, starty):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self, shape = "circle")
        self.hideturtle
        self.speed(0)
        self.penup()
        self.color(color)
        self.fd(0)
        self.setposition(startx, starty)

# function to invoked at firing frequency
    def enemy1_fire(self):
        x = self.xcor()
        y = self.ycor()
        bullet1 = Bullet()
        bullet1.setposition(x,y) # bullet will appear just above the player
        bullet1.setheading(270)
        bullet1.showturtle()
        self.a.append(bullet1)

num_Enemy1 = 1
enemies1 = []
for i in range(num_Enemy1): # design the enemies
    b = Enemy1("circle", "red", random.randint(-180,180), random.randint(-100,250))
    enemies1.append(b)

# Enemy1 class defined

player = Player("triangle", "white", 0, -390) # player declared

#key bindings
turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(player.turn_left,"Left")
turtle.onkey(player.turn_right,"Right")
turtle.onkey(player.accelerate,"Up")
#turtle.onkey(player.brake,"Down")


# define the firing intervals
freq1 = 8
```

Once the members of the game are decided, in the main game loop I define the movement and firing conditions. I make sure to clear the turtles once they go off screen thinking that should avoid slowing down, but haven't got any improvements by using `clear`.

```
# main game loop

while True:

    # enemy 1 loop

    for enemy1 in enemies1:
        enemy1.rt(10)
        enemy1.fd(10)
        freq1 = freq1 - 1
        if (freq1==0):
            enemy1.enemy1_fire()
            freq1 = 8


        for bullets in enemy1.a: # movement of each bullet defined
            y = bullets.ycor()
            y1 = y - 10
            bullets.sety(y1)

        for bullets in enemy1.a: # hide and delete bullets once they go off screen
            if (bullets.ycor()>390 or bullets.xcor()>390 or bullets.ycor()<-390 or bullets.xcor()<-390):
                bullets.hideturtle()
                bullets.clear() # should speed up the simulation
                del bullets # should speed up the simulation

delay = raw_input("Press enter to finish. > ")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors in your bullet handling logic that mean you're doing a lot more work than you need to on each frame (and some of the work may not do what you intend).

The first issue is in this line in the `Enemy` class:

```
a=[] # to store the bullets per enemy
```

The comment is wrong and extremely misleading. You are not storing the bullets *per enemy*, but rather you have only one list in a class variable and all of your `Enemy` instances share it. If you wanted a separate list for each instance, you'd need to move that line into the `__init__` method and write:

```
self.a = []
```

The fact that every enemy instance has a reference to the same list means that later when you use nested loops to iterate over `enemies1` and `enemy1.a`, you're in fact hitting every bullet in the whole game several times (once per enemy). That's probably not what you intend.

As I mentioned above, you could move the list into the instances. But an alternative is to keep the class variable list and instead just loop over it once, rather than repeatedly. The `Bullet` objects don't actually care about which `Enemy` fired them once they've been created, so you can arrive at correct behavior even with only one list of bullets. Just unindent the `for` loop over the bullets, and iterate on `Enemy.a`.

The other major issue with your code is that you're not correctly removing bullets that have gone out of bounds. In your code you have `del bullets`, but this only deletes the variable `bullets` from the local namespace, it doesn't remove the object referred to by that name from the list you're iterating on. So you gradually accumulate more and more bullets, which is probably what is slowing your code down.

Unfortunately removing items from a list while iterating on it is a bit perilous. If you just corrected the removal logic to use an index into the list (e.g. with `enumerate`), you'll find that you're only checking some of your bullets, not all of them. That's because each time you remove one bullet, all the later ones move up in the list, and so you'll skip over the next one in the list (since it is now in the index the removed bullet used to have). While there are a few possible workarounds (like iterating from the end of the list towards the beginning), often the best approach is to build a whole new list for the next frame, excluding the ones that are out of bounds.

```
new_bullet_list = []
for bullets in Enemy.a:
    if (bullets.ycor()>390 or bullets.xcor()>390 or bullets.ycor()<-390 or bullets.xcor()<-390):
        bullets.hideturtle()
        bullets.clear()
    else:
        new_bullet_list.append(bullets)
Enemy.a = new_bullet_list
```

As a side note, you should really try to improve your variable names. Using `a` as the name of your bullet list is needlessly terse. A name like `bullets` or `bullets_list` would be much more descriptive. And using `bullets` as the loop variable over your list of bullets is misleading since it's a single `Bullet` instance, not some plural collection of bullets. The numbers in `enemies1` and `enemy1` also don't do anything useful (normally numbers in a variable name suggest you should be using a list, but there's only one thing to handle here for each of those, the numbers are superfluous).

Comment: As per my understanding, all the member objects of a class get their individual copies of the member functions and variables, except for static variables and functions which are shared. So why does in my case, `a = []`, which isn't a static variable, shared by all the enemies? And I will improve my variable naming, even I get confused by it all the time.

Comment: You seem to be remembering rules from another programming language. C++ works like you describe, but Python does OOP differently.

Answer (score 1):

You're treating turtles (in the guise of bullets) as local entities that get garbage collected when you're done with them.  They aren't -- they are global (due to an internal turtle list) and never go away.  Instead of expecting to garbage collect them, keep track of them and reuse them.  Here's a rework of your code that takes this approach:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, mainloop
from random import randint

class Bullet(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.hideturtle()
        self.setundobuffer(None)
        self.shape('arrow')
        self.speed('fastest')
        self.color('white')
        self.setheading(270)
        self.penup()

# player class
class Player(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, sprite_shape, color, startx, starty):
        Turtle.__init__(self, shape=sprite_shape)
        self.hideturtle()
        self.speed('fastest')
        self.color(color)
        self.penup()
        self.goto(startx, starty)
        self.left(90)
        self.showturtle()

        self.setundobuffer(None)

    def turn_left(self):
        self.left(20)

    def turn_right(self):
        self.right(20)

    def move(self):
        self.forward(10)

# Define Enemy class
class Enemy(Turtle):

    available_bullets = [] # to store the bullets

    def __init__(self, sprite_shape, color, startx, starty):
        Turtle.__init__(self, shape=sprite_shape)
        self.hideturtle()
        self.speed('fastest')
        self.color(color)
        self.penup()
        self.setposition(startx, starty)
        self.showturtle()

        self.bullets = []  # my outstanding fired bullets

    # function to invoked at firing frequency
    def enemy_fire(self):
        if Enemy.available_bullets:
            bullet = Enemy.available_bullets.pop()
        else:
            bullet = Bullet()

        bullet.setposition(self.position()) # bullet will appear just above the player
        bullet.showturtle()

        self.bullets.append(bullet)

# draw white boundaries
def draw_border():
    pen = Turtle()
    pen.hideturtle()
    pen.speed('fastest')
    pen.color('white')

    pen.penup()
    pen.goto(-400, 400)
    pen.pendown()

    for _ in range(4):
        pen.forward(800)
        pen.right(90)

# set up the environment
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(850, 850)
screen.bgcolor('black')

draw_border()

num_Enemy = 2
enemies = []
for _ in range(num_Enemy): # design the enemies
    enemy = Enemy('circle', 'red', randint(-180, 180), randint(-100, 250))
    enemies.append(enemy)

player = Player('triangle', 'white', 0, -390) # player declared

# key bindings
screen.onkey(player.turn_left, 'Left')
screen.onkey(player.turn_right, 'Right')
screen.onkey(player.move, 'Up')
screen.listen()

# define the firing intervals
frequency = 8

# main game loop
while True:

    for enemy in enemies:
        enemy.right(10)
        enemy.forward(10)

        if frequency == 0:
            enemy.enemy_fire()

        frequency = (frequency + 1) % 9

        dead_bullets = []

        for bullet in enemy.bullets: # movement of each bullet defined
            bullet.forward(10)

            if not -390 < bullet.ycor() < 390:
                bullet.hideturtle()
                dead_bullets.append(bullet)

        for bullet in dead_bullets:
            enemy.bullets.remove(bullet)
            Enemy.available_bullets.append(bullet)

mainloop()
```

Your next major fix should be getting rid of `while True:`, which has no business in an event-based turtle environment, and use an `ontimer()` method of `Screen` instead.